# set path of JSESSIONID cookie created with HttpServletRequest.getSession(true)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat6

I am creating a session in one of the servlets of my web application using HttpServletRequest.getSession(true) which also creates a cookie JSESSIONID. I want to change the path associated with this cookie. I am trying to do this by setPath method but its not working. I am using tomcat6. Thanks in advance. Below is the code I am using

```
HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(true);
Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
if(cookies != null) {
    for (Cookie c : cookies)
    {
        if(c.getName().equals("JSESSIONID"))
        {
            c.setPath("somepath");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the cookie path but did not attached the modified cookie to the response. So on the client side, the change is never going to be recognized.

Add the modified cookie to the response like this `httpResponse.addCookie(c)` after modifying it.

Try this code:

```
HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(true);
Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
if(cookies != null) {
    for (Cookie c : cookies)
    {
        if(c.getName().equals("JSESSIONID"))
        {
            c.setPath("somepath");
            httpResponse.addCookie(c);
        }
    }
}
```

However it will not delete the existing cookie which has the old path instead it will create a new cookie with new path.

Unfortunately i could not able to find a way to delete the existing cookie. I have tried to remove the old cookie by setting it `maxAge` to `-1` but didn't worked. Here is the code that i've tried so far:

```
String jSessionId = null;

HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session == null) {
    session = request.getSession(true);
}

Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(cookies != null) {
    for (Cookie c : cookies)
    {
        if(c.getName().equals("JSESSIONID"))
        {
            jSessionId = c.getValue();

            c.setValue(null);
            c.setMaxAge(0);
            response.addCookie(c);
        }
    }
}

if(jSessionId != null) {
    Cookie c = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", jSessionId);
    c.setPath("/servlet/sayhello");
    c.setHttpOnly(true);
    response.addCookie(c);
}
```

There is no major issues by having 2 different cookies. So you can use the first code snippet if you are comfortable with having two cookies.

Comment: Thanks, For your reply. I have already tried the above approach but it didnt suffice my purpose. Instead what I do is as below          if(httpResponse.containsHeader("SET-COOKIE")){
    String sessionid = httpRequest.getSession().getId();
    httpResponse.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid
      + ";Path=path+";" );

Comment: @maverick can you update the OP with your solution?